# Python2.7 file.obj.write(str) not writing to file

Tags: python

new python2.7 user here. I've searched for similar queries and I can't quite see what I'm doing wrong. I have a short script to read though all the files in a directory, and reading each one in turn, write them to a single master file.

My code is below; I can see two things going wrong at this time (although I get no error messages), 1 - that it only appears to open the first file in the list its supposed to be looping through (so my guess is I've an error using glob?), and 2 - although the print(str) statements display to the console nps, the output file never gets written too.

I've double checked that the file exists, it is empty and I'm passing the correct path & filename in when I call the function.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import sys

filestoberecognised=sys.argv[1]
outputfile=sys.argv[2]

filecontents=glob.glob(filestoberecognised)
with open(outputfile,'w+') as f:
        for i, row in enumerate(filecontents):
                print(row) # this correctly prints to console
                f.write(row+'\n') # this should write the filename of the filestoberecognised to the outputfile
                with open(row,'r') as labfile:
                        for j, line in enumerate(labfile): # this should write words in label file
                                f.write('%s'%(line))
                                print('%s'%(line))
                labfile.close() # ensures each file looped through is closed 
                f.write('\n.\n') 
                f.flush()
f.close()
```

Comment: Well, for one, you don't need to use ``f.close()`` if you opened using ``with open() as f``, that's the whole point of the context manager, to call ``close`` at the end of the block. Likewise with ``labfile``

Comment: You can also just do ``for line in labfile:`` to iterate across the newlines in a file

Comment: Many thanks for both those tips, I've now updated my code as advised but I'm still having the same two issues - that its only looking at 1 file in the directory and the single master file is not being written to. Thanks again.